# Translation of a Line from Caesar's De Bello Gallico 5.29

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check, sentence-translation, latin-to-english-translation, gaius-iulius-caesar

I am currently having trouble working through a line from Caesar's *De Bello Gallico*

> Cottae quidem atque eorum, qui dissentirent, consilium quem habere exitum?

Currently, I have this as "Indeed what result was the advice of Cotta and of those who disagreed?".
However, this does not seem quite correct to me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

This is part of an accusativus cum infinitivo, indirect speech depending on a previous finite verb. What makes it difficult to translate is the direct question converted into an a.c.i. Your translation is close.

> Indeed, that the advice of Cotta—and of those who disagreed—had what result?

You could translate it more liberally and convert the a.c.i. into direct speech:

> The advice of Cotta, indeed, and of those who disagreed—what result would it have?

Comment: The finite verb in question, in case the OP is unsure, is at the beginning of the chapter: "Contra ea Titurius clamitabat..." Thus: "Titurius exclaimed that the advice of Cotta...etc."

Comment: @brianpck: Yeah I had also looked it up. The problem is that the construction is still pretty untranslatable!